# Will domain name with keyword "Android" makes any legal problem?

Tags: seo, domains, html, php, javascript

I am planning to buy a domain with keyword "Android" to my website. But i am worried about having any legal problem doing this. If i am buying what all things i have to look forward?

Comment: As it is, this is really too broad and opinion-based to answer specifically. In brief, you should search the trademark databases in the countries that your website will target. If you're intending to focus on the same areas as the trademark was granted for, then it's unwise to buy a domain under which you'll have a legal risk in using.

Comment: As long as you are creating a site that is positive and not android sucks, then you generally should be okay. Brands only go after those who detract from their brand and not those who advance the brand. As well, you cannot confuse the brand so that users think you are the brand or have a relationship to the brand. If you are clearly a support site, for example, then you should have no problems. Trademark and copyright law are fairly clear and simple.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this text https://developer.android.com/legal.html it seems that you can't use the Android name in any way that goes 'beyond describing it as being intended to use with the Android platform' (which I agree is sort of vague).

I suppose, therefore, that it depends on how you are planning to use the name.